# Mouse rotated 90°

Tags: mouse

I have the same issue with my Trust 189519 wireless mouse. I missclicked something then my mouse rotated. Rotation is back to normal when using another mouse (HP H3C53AA) (S/N 7ch53526gv)

Only thing i recently installed regarding peripherals is Logitech Gaming Software for my G920 Racing wheel. Even closing that software or reinstalling the mouse drivers didn't change anything.

I already tried some of the solutions from similar questions:

- Re-plugging the mouse (Doesn't work)
- Re-installing the driver (Doesn't work)
- Rotating my screens forth and back (Doesn't work)
- Exiting the Logitech software (Doesn't work)
- Trying to find a setting in any mouse related software for it (Doesn't work)
- Pressing random mouse button combinations (Doesn't work)
- Removing the battery from the mouse for quite some time (Doesn't work)
- Use another mouse (Works, but is no solution)

Comment: There is no support from that particular Manufacturer P.S: Atleast no support that might answer before 2019 ;)

Comment: Is the question still visible while marked as duplicate?

Comment: Have you tried the mouse on a different computer?  If the problem goes away, you can always reinstall windows on your machine to fix the problem (if you can't find another solution).  If the problem persists, then it's probably something only the manufacturer could fix (since it would be directly related to the mouse's internal workings, independent of driver or software installed).

Comment: Contact Logitech (if they are manufacturer)